# Using html5 instead of flash

Tags: html, flash

I've converted (via google swiffy) an swf file to html. Now I'm trying to add it in a Joomla(3.5.1)  article. I can't. Could someone help me please?

Comment: Did you try adding i-frame to your article? The i-frame could load the Swiffy HTML as frame source.

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved it with i-frame.

Comment: Glad it's fixed. I did not downvote but I will +1 for solving your own issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a free joomla extension named  [Sourcerer](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/sourcerer)  , Using its insert codes button , you can insert your html5 code inside any joomla article.

Here is a short tutorial on how to use this plugin https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiFa1Jq8igQ.

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved it with i-frame. It seems to me easier than Sourcerer.

Comment: Great.we are happy as long the problem is solved for you.